# How to give any shape to Views?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to give any shape to Views in android

I want following background to textview.

[image: Please check image...]

Answer (score 0):

You can create shapes using xml drawables in Android. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

But the background you want is not straightforward using xml. So I recommend creating background using any image editor and set it as background of the textview.

Another approach would be to create vector drawable for the required shape which is supported from android API 21. Here is a good tutorial to create your your own shapes and images
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e

Answer (score 0):

To customize a View you should create a [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). Create a new class by extending the `View` class, implement all public constructors and override the [onDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) function. When using in the layout file give the full path of the custom view:

```
<com.example.ownview.MyDrawView
        android:id="@+id/myDrawView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```